# POST method returns wrong URL when BindingResult has errors

Tags: java, spring-mvc, http-post, thymeleaf

I have this POST method which only validates a form and returns a confirmation view if the form is validated and I want to send back to the register screen if any field is wrong. In this case if the BindingResult object has errors, the system send the user back to the form screen but the URL shown is "/registerConfirmation" which should only be in case the form has no errors.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/registerConfirmation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView confirmRegister(@Valid @ModelAttribute("form") RegistrationForm form, BindingResult result){
    logger.info("Sending registration data");
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        modelAndView.setViewName("register");
        modelAndView.addObject("form", form);
        return modelAndView;
    }
    //more code here

    return modelAndView;

}
```

I dont know what I'm missing as I have seen methods like this in many other posts. Any help??

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve your issue is to use redirect:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/registerConfirmation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String confirmRegister(@Valid @ModelAttribute("form") RegistrationForm form, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attr){
     logger.info("Sending registration data");
     if(result.hasErrors()){
       attr.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.form", result);
       attr.addFlashAttribute("form", form);
       return "redirect:/register";
     }
     //more code here    
     return "redirect:/registerConfirmation";
}
```

and in your register GET method you should check:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showRegister(Model model) {
     ....
    if (!model.containsAttribute("form")) {
        model.addAttribute("form", new RegistrationForm());
    }
    .....
}
```

you can read more [in this article](https://gerrydevstory.com/2013/07/11/preserving-validation-error-messages-on-spring-mvc-form-post-redirect-get/)

Also don't forget to create GET method with `registerConfirmation` value.

Comment: Hi Enigo, I have  a get method, I tried using redirect but I loose the data with or without errors.

Comment: So, @KrOMaG, do you still have some issues?

Comment: yes, I can print out values of my object in /registerConfirmation but, when,  from this model I re-send  to the same POST method /registerConfirmation I get a nullpointerException as if I had an empty object!. I also have a question, why a need a register GET and POST method and a GET and POST method for registerConfirmation as well? many thanks!

Comment: Well, you don't need all for methods if you don't need them actually :) GET method basically works when you enter your page. POST - when user presses Submit button. So it's your choice how many methods you need. I wrote about GET method for registerConfirmation 'cos I thought that you want to display that page too. What object is null when you re-send?

Comment: I'm following the example in the link you posted earlier, and now I'm getting a "Request method 'GET' not supported". I want to press the submit button twice, first to validate the data and show it in the confirmation screen, and from this screen(if the user agree with it) send it again and store the new user in the database. Wow, it looked easier when I thought of this.

Comment: Yes @Enigo, I m just a graduate and I find this a bit confusing yet. Everything ok, you were so helpful. This is a small step, let's go with the register process, I want to build my app (just an online library for learning) and I am scared of every decision I make. I want to build a small arquitecture but I always think that I'm wrong. Thanks again!!!

Comment: @KrOMaG glad to hear that! :) don't be so scared  'cos actually spring mvc is easier than it might look like. I'm pretty sure that after a few months of studying you will think that too. BTW don't forget to accept the answers :)

Comment: accept the answers? I click on the tick to turn it green, is that what you mean?